# How to load images into listview

Tags: c#, image, listview

I have this `ListView` and I want to load images to that `ListView`. And I have file paths in which the images are stored. I want to loop for each images contained in the file path and load them into the listview. And I don't know how to do it. Will you please help me? The following is my unfinished code. Thank you.

```
DataTable dtPath = new DataTable();
dtPath = ContrPtMRD.SelectFilePaths();

foreach (DataRow rows in dtPath.Rows)
{
    lvPtMedicalRecord.????
}
```

Comment: Check this out: It is the [msdn forum post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winforms/thread/876b6517-7306-44b0-88df-caebf3b1c10f) that provides the help you may need. :)

Comment: @Mr_Green How can I make the images in listview appear larger? I try changing `lvPtMedicalRecord.LargeImageList = myImageList;` but the images are still small.

Comment: First of all your images should be large by default. If they are large then try [`ImageList.ImageSize`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.imagelist.imagesize(v=vs.100).aspx) property.

Comment: and even changing `View` property will also work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems you are storing the `Image locations` in the same DataTable. It will be understandable if you store those image Locations in a `ImageList` while processing the foreach loop. Here is the sample code:

```
lvPtMedicalRecord.LargeImageList = myImageList;  //Attaching ImageList to the ListView
int imageIndex = 0;
foreach (DataRow rows in dtPath.Rows)
{
   //Store the paths of the images in the same DataTable (I can think of this only)
   myImageList.Images.Add(Image.FromFile(row[0].ToString());
   ListViewItem lvi = new ListViewItem();
   lvi.ImageIndex = imageIndex; //Index of the Image present in the `ImageList`
   imageIndex++;
   lvPtMedicalRecord.Items.Add(lvi);
}
```

Update:

For making Images large:

```
 myImageList.ImageSize = new System.Drawing.Size(112, 112); // width, height
```